# How to mount this sink?

Tags: sink, brackets, antique

[image]
Hello I'm new here. I've looked into sink wall brackets. (I prefer to hang rather than using a pedestal). I cant find  hanging brackets for the back or the shelf type to hang it that way. Would it ONLY hang by 3 screws? I'm dyslexic, please post pictures of what to do.

Answer (score 3):

This hangs by the 3 "screws"...   However I have seen sinks like this twice in my life and they were both being supported by BOLTS.

Either with a BAS (big ass screw) or BAB you will for sure have to go into framing.

The leverage the whole top of the frame has with the three screws is more than enough hold for just a sink - there is no vanity to support.   This works in similar fashion to your top kitchen cabinet shelves.

If you bolt it, it will certainly look better.   And you can square the bolts and repaint them so it doesn't even look like a bolt.

Comment: Yup. Lag bolts into framing. Which might mean opening up the wall to provide framing (blocking) in the right location.